# Alternatives to Mendeley or Qiqqa to manage PDF and autoextract meta-data?

Tags: software, reference-managers, digital-libraries

Having been a long term user of both Mendeley and Qiqqa, I have to switch to another tool that offers in particular:

- the ability to bulk upload PDF and autoextract meta-data / bibTex info
- manage all the relevant PDF, including annotations
- be available as desktop version, i.e. with a locally managed database and library

Unfortunately Zotero, Endnote and other pure reference managers don't seem to have a usable content management systems for PDF's, that allows bulk PDF processing, like Mendeley or Qiqqa have.

I also don't want to switch to a pure content / document management system, which likely would not have the meta-data extraction and bibTex management capabilities.

My preference would be something like Qiqqa, which includes a lot of features I find very useful, including auto-tagging, relationship extraction, mind-mapping etc. but have not found anything that comes even close to that. Unfortunately due to Google changing it's access methods, Qiqqa is not useable anymore for me.

Mendeley would have been an acceptable alternative, but I have to move the library occasionally from one computer to another, and since Elsevier started to encrypt its SQLite3 datastore, it's not possible to move the respective folders to a new location.

I have looked at various alternatives (also paid ones), but have not found anything suitable.

For any recommendation I would be immensely greatful.

Comment: Is coding your own tool to meet your needs a viable option?

Comment: I'm sure it would be a fun project do (or perhaps to tweak Qiqqa, since it has gone open source), but I don't have the time to do so.